# Difference between Adjacency matrix and Laplacian matrix (Dynamical Process Perspective)

Tags: social-networks

We can represent a simple connected graph $G$ using mathematically as adjacency matrix, $A$. There are other matrices related to the graph which is very useful is the Laplacian matrix $L=D-A$ where D is the diagonal matrix contains the degree of the nodes. It is mentioned that spectrum of the Laplacian matrix is useful for the dynamical perspective on networks. It has also been reported that the maximum eigenvalue i.e. $\lambda_{max}$ of adjacency matrix gives the threshold of the disease spreading process [1] (is a dynamic process).

I am not clear, what kind of information we can achieve from the spectrum of the adjacency matrix but not from Laplacian matrix and vice versa (where both are two types of dynamical process). If anyone suggest some reference or article which can clear me is also welcome.

[1] Y. Wang, D. Chakrabarti, C. Wang, and C. Faloutsos, Epidemic Spreading in Real Networks: An Eigenvalue Viewpoint, in 22nd International Symposium on Reliable Distribute Systems (SRDS03) (IEEE Computer Society, Los Alamitos, 2003), p. 25.

Thanks a lot.